Passing Osgi.logfile location as vmargument with environment-variable in Path
I'm currently trying to generalize the location of my logfiles, including rcp/p2 logs.
For that i pass
-vmargs
-Dosgi.logfile=... 

in my program.ini so far so good:
Putting a hard-coded path in the osgi property works fine, as
-Dosgi.logfile=C:\\Users\\USERNAME.log\\rcp.log

creates a log file when p2 runs as expected.
However i want to reference the Userprofile with environment-variables, so: How do i reference the Userprofile/java user.home as vmargs correctly?
I allready tried some different syntax and references i could find:
-Dosgi.logfile=%USERPROFILE%\.log\rcp.log
-Dosgi.logfile=user.home\.log\rcp.log
-Dosgi.logfile="user.home"\.log\rcp.log
-Dosgi.logfile=@user.home\.log\rcp.log
-Dosgi.logfile=$user.home$\.log\rcp.log

...none of these work.

I don't think there is any substitution done on the -vmargs section. Source code is here
